# Upload a Mesh to Scene that Created with Unity WebGL

Tags: javascript, web-applications, unity-webgl, unitywebrequest

I want to develop a webapp with Unity WebGL. I want to create a html button for uploading meshes. The uploaded mesh is going to display on the Unity's scene. How can i do this?

I tried to develop with gpt but its code has many errors.